# Inverse function to $f(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, inverse, quadratics, hyperbolic-functions

> Let $f$ be a function defined by $$f(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$ Find $f^{-1}(x)$. Domain for $x$ is $R$

My attempt,

Let $$f^{-1}(x)=a$$

$$x=f(a)$$

$$=\frac{e^a-e^{-a}}{2}$$

$$2x=e^a-e^{-a}$$

Let $$e^a=u$$

$$2x=u-u^{-1}$$

$$u^2-2xu-1=0$$

Solving $u$ by quadratic formula.

$$u=x\pm \sqrt{x^2+1}$$

$$e^a=x\pm \sqrt{x^2+1}$$

$$a=\ln(x\pm \sqrt{x^2+1})$$

$$f^{-1}(x)=\ln(x\pm \sqrt{x^2+1})$$

But my tutor said I'm wrong. Why?

Comment: It might help to know that, for you example, $f(x)=\text{sinh}(x)$.

Comment: Essentially, it cannot be $\pm\sqrt{x^{2}+1}$ because $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $e^{b}>0$ for ANY $b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe because $x-\sqrt{x^2+1}<0$

Answer (score 3):

Your tutor wants you to find the right root of your equation. Clearly, if $f$ is bijective, there can be only **one** answer.
Note that $x^2+1>x^2$, so $\sqrt{x^2+1}>\left|x\right|$. So $x-\sqrt{x^2+1}<0$ whatever $x$ is (which can't be right because this is the value of $e^a$ which has to be positive).
So the right answer is 
$$f^{-1}(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$$
sometimes (generally ?) noted ${\rm Argsh}(x)$.